# Can't connect to Postgresql database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database from my Spring Boot application but am having trouble doing so. This is the exception trace I am seeing:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ion.CourseApplication.main(CourseApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

My application.yml looks like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://<server_addr>/<db_name>
    username: postgres
    password: <pwd>
```

And I have the following dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

I have searched for this issue on Stackoverflow but as far as I can tell, I am doing all the required steps. Can anyone help?

Comment: what's that driver version? i'm using 42.0.0, and the clasname is org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: Remove the `driverClassName` you don't need it. JDBC itself will deduct which driver to need (and Spring also helps you with that).

Comment: @rmalchow I think that's an older version (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql). I tried changing it to `42.0.0` and driverClassName to `org.postgresql.Driver` and now I am getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

Comment: oh well - that's another question entirely. you have to tell hibernate which SQL dialect to use. so that would be "hibernate.dialect=PostgreSQLDialect" i guess?

Comment: if my answer below answered this question, please accept it.

Comment: sorry, in spring this would be configured like this: "spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect: PostgreSQLDialect" in your application.yml

Comment: can you please show your hibernate related config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver classname is not correct. I just checked the version you're using (which is also wildly out-of-date) - it doesn't even contain "org.postgresql.jdbc" as a package.

The driver classname should be:

```
org.postgresql.Driver
```

Since most jar files are simple ZIP files, you can always manually unzip the jar and manually examin what's inside (most IDEs will do that for you). With errors such as this ("Cannot load class" or "Class not found") this can help to determine wether the class is there or not. In your case, it's not.

Comment: With this modification alone (keeping the version as `9.4-1206-jdbc42`), I am still getting the exceptions I put in the comments below my original post.

Comment: yes. i answered in a comment there. however, this is unrelated to the initial question.

Comment: That did the trick. Also, as @M. Deinum suggested removing `driverClassName` altogether while keeping everything else the same fixed it also. Thanks!